"pod install" redownloads the same pod of different versions
My podfile:
pod 'AppLovinSDK'
pod 'AppLovinMediationByteDanceAdapter'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationPangle'

I run pod install and get the following log:
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Ads-Global 6.1.0.6
Installing Ads-Global 6.1.0.7 (was 6.1.0.6)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 16 dependencies from the Podfile and 25 total pods installed.

I didn't find podspec for GoogleMobileAdsMediationPangle but for AppLovinMediationByteDanceAdapter:
https://github.com/AppLovin/AppLovin-MAX-SDK-iOS/commits/master/ByteDance/AppLovinMediationByteDanceAdapter.podspec
both Ads-Global 6.1.0.6 and 6.1.0.7 versions are supported. So why doesn't it download the lower version which exists in both adapters?
Edited
My current solution is to hardcode a version of the adapter/adapters to force them using 6.1.0.6 simultaneously. But can't cocoapods do that automatically?

What's the podfile.lock before the pod install?

@Larme podfile.lock shows that one adapter uses 6.1.0.6 and another one uses 6.1.0.7. And I'm not able to check how it works or not properly because adding adapters is performed through podfile only (not swift code) and these adapters are fully optional.
